# How I can include prototype scripts on ionic2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, prototype

I want use a file with some function prototype like `Array.prototype.x( ... )`, but I don't know how I can include it as global.

Example:

**Array.ts**

```
Array.prototype.x = function(i) {return this[i]}
Array.prototype.y = () => {return true}
Array.prototype.z = () => {return true}
```

**pages/home/home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    constructor() {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        let a [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
        console.log(a.x()); // see Array.prototype.x()
        console.log(a.y()); // see Array.prototype.y()
        console.log(a.z()); // see Array.prototype.z()
    }
}
```

> P.S: My prototype file have too much functions

Comment: Just include it in head and it will work.

Comment: Well, my "Array.ts" have too much functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just import the file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import './Array';
@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    constructor() {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        let a [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
        console.log(a.x()); // see Array.prototype.x()
        console.log(a.y()); // see Array.prototype.y()
        console.log(a.z()); // see Array.prototype.z()
    }
}
```